# Summing a Column with Multiple Data Types in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL and am trying to write a query in sql server to get sums of documents week. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    [table].[week],
    SUM(ISNULL([table].[documents],0))
FROM 
    [table]
JOIN 
    (VALUES (15,187293),...other pairs...,(127,120918)) AS Outside ([ID],[Organization]) ON Outside.[ID]=[table].[ID]
                                 AND Outside.[Organization] = [table].[Organization]
GROUP BY 
    week
```

This same query worked on a different table (formatted exactly the same) outputting documents per week, but when I run it on this table, I get the error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '#N/A' to data type int.

There is nothing in the documents column that looks like #N/A. How can I make this sum appropriately?

Comment: It's telling you that you have the value `'#N/A'` in your table and that the conversion to an `int` is failing. Which isn't surprising, that value isn't a number.

Comment: At a guess, either `ID` or `Organisation` is th datatype `varchar`. If you're storing a numerical value, you should be using a numerical data type, not a `varchar`. `varchar` isn't a one size fits all datatype.

Answer (score 1):

To find the offending rows, run the query:

```
select t.*
from table t
where id = '#N/A' or organization = '#N/A';
```

Or better yet:

```
select t.*
from table t
where try_convert(int, id) is null or try_convert(int, organization) is null;
```

You can fix the problem by using appropriate types in the `outside` set of values.  That is, one or both of the values should be in single quotes so they are strings rather than numbers.